# How do you configure it so a published article promoted to another page instead of "front page"?

Tags: views

I have a main menu with:

"Home" -basic page 
 "Contact us" -the default drupal contact form
 "news" - which I want all the news articles to dynamically publish to the top so that when people click on news they see the latest article.

I thought that making a menu item in the form of an "article page" might do it but that only seemed to be comfortable with a single article. I made it into a book and it has allowed me to create a page but the formatting has gone dead weird so I would like to be able to create my articles and click an option which allows me to promote my articles to the news page. Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Views, you can use "promoted to front page" as a filter value, so that things with that box checked can also be "promoted" to any page view that takes that as a filter.

If you don't want to us the native "promoted to front page" checkbox, but would rather have a separate checkbox just for that page, you can add a custom field to your content type(s) and use that as a filter value instead.

Comment: Thanks that helps. Would you be able to elaborate a bit on the filters and how they work?

Comment: @Magpie This is a very broad question, and as Serpiente pointed out, there is a lot of available documentation. You could start with [the Views online help page on filters](http://views-help.doc.logrus.com/help/views/filter).

Comment: There's also [this question about a Views tutorial](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/673/where-is-a-detailed-tutorial-on-views)

Answer (score 1):

[Views](http://drupal.org/project/views)

> **You need Views if**
>
> - You like the default front page view, but you find you want to sort    it differently.
> - You like the default taxonomy/term view, but you find you want to    sort it differently; for example, alphabetically.
> - You use /tracker, but you want to restrict it to posts of a certain    type.
> - You like the idea of the 'article' module, but it doesn't display    articles the way you like.
> - You want a way to display a block with the 5 most recent posts of    some particular type.
> - You want to provide 'unread forum posts'.
> - You want a monthly archive similar to the typical Movable    Type/Wordpress archives that displays a link to the in the form of
>     "Month, YYYY (X)" where X is the number of posts that month, and
>     displays them in a block. The links lead to a simple list of posts
>     for that month.
>
> Views can do a lot more than that, but those are some of the obvious
>   uses of Views.

[Views Tutorials](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/673/where-is-a-detailed-tutorial-on-views)

Comment: I have views. How do I configure it to solve my problem though?

Comment: there are tons of howto's out there..